# RestKit 0.2x : how to check for the existence of a keyPath before applying the mapping

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, restkit-0.20

In my app I do something like this:

```
[itineraryMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"inboundInfo" toKeyPath:@"inboundInfo" withMapping:flightInfoMapping]];
```

but the key `inboundInfo` may and may not return with the `JSON` according to some criteria, I don't want to add a whole new (big) response descriptor to the `objectManager` to satisfy this case, however, is there a way to check that the `inboundInfo` key path exists or not before adding the property mapping ?

p.s. in case `inboundInfo` didn't return with the `JSON` the above line will make a crash, removing the line the app will be fine.

**EDIT:** solved using `RKDynamicMapping` like this:

```
//configuring the dynamic mapping
[dynamicMapping setObjectMappingForRepresentationBlock:^RKEntityMapping *(id representation) {

    if([[representation objectForKey:@"inboundInfo"] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        if(![itineraryMapping.propertyMappings containsObject:inboundInfoMapping]) { //to prevent adding inboundInfoMapping more than once
            [itineraryMapping addPropertyMapping:inboundInfoMapping];
        }
    }

    //if inboundInfo is not a dictionary simply return the itineraryMapping without adding inboundInfoMapping on it
    return itineraryMapping;

}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `RKDynamicMapping` to run a block of code which analyses the response and decides which mapping you wish to apply.

http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKDynamicMapping.html

(Dynamic Object Mapping section) https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping

Comment: the method setObjectMapping: whenValueOfKeyPath: isEqualTo  is outdated in docs because it does not exist in 0.2x ...